# ARKit Feature Points Not on Planes

Tags: swift, arkit

I have run into some interesting behavior. I am trying to have the user click on a point and then put a sphere where the user has clicked. The very first step is of course to get the point where the user touches. That is done as follows:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let location = touches.first?.location(in: sceneView) {
            let locationsInSpace = sceneView.hitTest(location, types: .featurePoint)
            
            if let locationInSpace = locationsInSpace.first {
                addDot(at: locationInSpace) //Add the sphere
            }
        }
    }
```

This works as I expect on an iPhone 13 Pro Max running iOS 17 beta, and an iPad Pro running iPadOS 17 beta. However, on an iPad Air 5 running iPadOS 16.6 the points are not correct. The points are appearing directly in front of my device, when I expect them to be "on" the plane in the scene. What I mean by this is if I point the devices towards a door and I touch on the door I would expect the points to be "on" the door. This is what happens on the iPhone and iPad Pro that I test on, but on the iPad Air 5 the points are appearing always in front of the device in the virtual space which is not what I am expecting.

Is there anything unique about the hardware of the iPad Air 5 that might cause this? Or is this most likely an issue in iPadOS 16.6? Unfortunately I am not able to update the iPad Air 5 to see if that is the issue.